# Error on getting API response (HERE maps rest API)

Tags: flutter, dart, here-api

I'm new to flutter so bear with me that. I am currently making an application that uses HERE Maps API to get location data, but I'm getting "An error has occurred!", which comes when snapshot has no data.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final hereRestLocation = hereRestLocationFromJson(jsonString);

HereRestLocation hereRestLocationFromJson(String str) => HereRestLocation.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String hereRestLocationToJson(HereRestLocation data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class HereRestLocation {
    List<Item> items;

    HereRestLocation({
        required this.items,
    });

    factory HereRestLocation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HereRestLocation(
        items: List<Item>.from(json["items"].map((x) => Item.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "items": List<dynamic>.from(items.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

//from here
// Future<http.Response> fetchHereRestLocation(http.Client client) async {
//   return client.get(Uri.parse('https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?at=40.7307999,-73.9973085&limit=2&q=Liberty&apiKey=**My API key here**'));
// }

List <HereRestLocation> parseHereRestLocation(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<HereRestLocation>((json) => HereRestLocation.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

Future <List<HereRestLocation>> fetchHereRestLocation(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client.get(Uri.parse('https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?at=40.7307999,-73.9973085&limit=2&q=Liberty&apiKey=**My API key here**'));
  // return parseHereRestLocation(response.body);
  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parseHereRestLocation,response.body);
}

//to here
class Item {
    String title;
    String id;
    String language;
    String resultType;
    String localityType;
    ItemAddress address;
    Highlights highlights;

    Item({
        required this.title,
        required this.id,
        required this.language,
        required this.resultType,
        required this.localityType,
        required this.address,
        required this.highlights,
    });

    factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
        title: json["title"],
        id: json["id"],
        language: json["language"],
        resultType: json["resultType"],
        localityType: json["localityType"],
        address: ItemAddress.fromJson(json["address"]),
        highlights: Highlights.fromJson(json["highlights"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "title": title,
        "id": id,
        "language": language,
        "resultType": resultType,
        "localityType": localityType,
        "address": address.toJson(),
        "highlights": highlights.toJson(),
    };
}

class ItemAddress {
    String label;
    String countryCode;
    String countryName;
    String state;
    String county;
    String city;

    ItemAddress({
        required this.label,
        required this.countryCode,
        required this.countryName,
        required this.state,
        required this.county,
        required this.city,
    });

    factory ItemAddress.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ItemAddress(
        label: json["label"],
        countryCode: json["countryCode"],
        countryName: json["countryName"],
        state: json["state"],
        county: json["county"],
        city: json["city"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "label": label,
        "countryCode": countryCode,
        "countryName": countryName,
        "state": state,
        "county": county,
        "city": city,
    };
}

class Highlights {
    List<Title> title;
    HighlightsAddress address;

    Highlights({
        required this.title,
        required this.address,
    });

    factory Highlights.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Highlights(
        title: List<Title>.from(json["title"].map((x) => Title.fromJson(x))),
        address: HighlightsAddress.fromJson(json["address"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "title": List<dynamic>.from(title.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "address": address.toJson(),
    };
}

class HighlightsAddress {
    List<Title> label;
    List<Title> city;

    HighlightsAddress({
        required this.label,
        required this.city,
    });

    factory HighlightsAddress.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HighlightsAddress(
        label: List<Title>.from(json["label"].map((x) => Title.fromJson(x))),
        city: List<Title>.from(json["city"].map((x) => Title.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "label": List<dynamic>.from(label.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "city": List<dynamic>.from(city.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Title {
    int start;
    int end;

    Title({
        required this.start,
        required this.end,
    });

    factory Title.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Title(
        start: json["start"],
        end: json["end"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "start": start,
        "end": end,
    };
}



void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Isolate Demo';

    return const MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<HereRestLocation>>(
        future: fetchHereRestLocation(http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('An error has occurred!'),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return MapList(items: snapshot.data!);
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MapList extends StatelessWidget {
  const MapList({super.key, required this.items});

  final List<HereRestLocation> items;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(items[index].title);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

If needed, JSON response for the above API call from browser is like:

> {"items":[{"title":"Liberty","id":"here:pds:place:840dr5r0-54fff946ce707baf510ad4123b26813d","language":"en","ontologyId":"here:cm:ontology:liberty","resultType":"place","address":{"label":"Liberty, 2509 Victory Blvd, Staten Island, NY 10314-6634, United States","countryCode":"USA","countryName":"United States","stateCode":"NY","state":"New York","county":"Richmond","city":"Staten Island","district":"Graniteville","street":"Victory Blvd","postalCode":"10314-6634","houseNumber":"2509"},"position":{"lat":40.61038,"lng":-74.14678},"access":[{"lat":40.61022,"lng":-74.14673}],"distance":18390,"categories":[{"id":"700-7600-0116","name":"Gas Station","primary":true}],"chains":[{"id":"4792","name":"Liberty"}],"references":[{"supplier":{"id":"core"},"id":"1130469039"},{"supplier":{"id":"yelp"},"id":"KbW5ssi1UCdbVd_Oodxe7w"}],"contacts":[{"phone":[{"value":"+17189826797"},{"value":"+17189829369"}],"www":[{"value":"http‍://www.liberty.edu"}]}],"openingHours":[{"text":["Mon-Sun: 00:00 - 24:00"],"isOpen":true,"structured":[{"start":"T000000","duration":"PT24H00M","recurrence":"FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU"}]}],"payment":{"methods":[{"id":"mastercard","accepted":true}]}},{"title":"Liberty","id":"here:pds:place:840dr4y0-57e980bf79d04227a9cd14a94e7c9384","language":"en","ontologyId":"here:cm:ontology:liberty","resultType":"place","address":{"label":"Liberty, 118 US Highway 202, Ringoes, NJ 08551-1920, United States","countryCode":"USA","countryName":"United States","stateCode":"NJ","state":"New Jersey","county":"Hunterdon","city":"Ringoes","street":"US Highway 202","postalCode":"08551-1920","houseNumber":"118"},"position":{"lat":40.46667,"lng":-74.8599},"access":[{"lat":40.46666,"lng":-74.85998}],"distance":78526,"categories":[{"id":"700-7600-0116","name":"Gas Station","primary":true},{"id":"600-6000-0061","name":"Convenience Store"}],"chains":[{"id":"4792","name":"Liberty"}],"contacts":[{"phone":[{"value":"+19088066633"}],"www":[{"value":"http‍://www.liberty.edu","categories":[{"id":"700-7600-0116"}]}]}],"payment":{"methods":[{"id":"mastercard","accepted":true}]}}]}

I tried using https://app.quicktype.io/ to get classes as well, but here I am.

Comment: Check the response code. print("${response.statusCode}"); It should be 200.

Comment: @VivekChib I checked. The response code is 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<HereRestLocation> fetch() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(URL));

    final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      HereRestLocation hereRestLocation = HereRestLocation.fromJson(jsonResponse);

      for (Item item in hereRestLocation.items) {
        debugPrint(item.id.toString());
      }

      return hereRestLocation;
    } else {
      throw Exception("Something Went Wrong");
    }
  }
```

Comment: This was for a project of mine so it took time as had other codes as well. Actually it worked with some changes to this code, but as this can be taken as reference I'll mark this as the final answer